# Should Visual Studio 2008 throw an accessibility error (508) with a 100% table driven layout?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, accessibility, section508

I'm trying to make sure my work is 508 compliant more and more these days, but noticed that VS2008 doesn't throw an error if you have a 100% table driven layout instead of css.

I always thought that to be 508 compliant you needed to drop the "tables for layout" idea ...

If this is true, how can I force studio to make these errors instead of warnings?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that VS2008 has no sense of *intent*. Even under 508, it's correct to use tables to present tabular data. The compiler can look at a layout and see that it includes complexly-nested tables, but not whether the use is incorrect.

Comment: Ha! intent was the word I was looking for +1

Comment: good point, so the developer should know this and make sure to avoid tables for layout (obviously tabular data is still valid)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe using or not using tables for layout makes your site 508 compliant or not. It's whether you have title and alt tags for table cells, images, links, don't depend on Javascript, etc.

Comment: 508 also likes you to have good topic headers, and have navigations elements and things in the correct order, which table layouts often break.

Answer (score 2):

Tables are still the correct and valid way to display tables of data.

Answer (score 1):

As you write here "100% table driven layout", the error would be correct. Layout should NOT be done with tables, but instead with DIV tags.  The design world that has accepted CSS standards goes nuts when things aren't designed appropriately with DIVs, as they hate TABLE layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Section 508 (and even the [WCAG guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WAI-WEBCONTENT-19990505/#gl-table-markup)) don't explicitly forbid tables for layout. It is to be avoided, but if it cannot (owing for legacy systems I suppose) then the table is OK if it reads the same linearly as it does when presented as a table.

Another thing I have learned is that layout table markup should avoid certain elements of data tables, especially `th` tags, since this can kick a screenreader into "tables" mode which can screw with the whole linearization thing.

So the real reason VS isn't doing anything to warn you is like @Jekke said, it can't tell the context.